# Show only top 3 entries and rest as "Others" in stacked barplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar chart showing the monthly incoming and outgoing calls. When I create a stacked bar chart I want to be able to show the stacks for the top 3 contacts (with highest call duration) and show the rest as others. Is there a way of automating this in R?

My present chart looks like this:

[image: Call Summary Plot]

My dataframe (callsummary) can be downloaded (3kb) from the link below:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4077057/callsummary.csv
```

My code for ggplot is:

```
ggplot(callsummary) + 
  aes(x = Bill, y = Duration) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill =Contact) ) + 
  facet_grid(~Direction) + 
  labs(list(title = "Monthly Call Summary", x = "Month", y = "Total Call duration in Minutes")) + 
  geom_hline(data = subset(monthlysummary, Direction == "In"), aes(yintercept = mean(Duration))) + 
  geom_hline(data = subset(monthlysummary, Direction == "Out"), aes(yintercept = mean(Duration)))
```

Note that I have created another dataframe called monthlysummary just to to be able to add a y-intercept which is equal to the average call duration in both "In" and "Out" grids.

The monthlysummary dataframe looks like this:

```
    Direction Bill   Duration Amount
       <fctr> <fctr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1       Out  April      9.3   1.40
2        In  April     55.3   0.00
3       Out    May     32.5   4.89
4        In    May     76.9   0.00
5       Out   June     17.4   2.62
6        In   June    114.3   0.00
```

Comment: Additional rows from "Out" category added

Comment: The preferred way to post your data is using `dput`

Comment: I would suggest dodged barplots instead of stacked barplots so that you might make comparisons along a non aligned y axis. For that matter if you are making summaries of the mean, you should consider plotting grouped boxplots.

Comment: @SushantG, to incorporate @shayaa's suggestion, add `position = "dodge"` in `geom_bar` for dodged barplots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Read the csv file
callsummary <- read.csv("callsummary.csv", header = T)
# Remove the first column which are row numbers
callsummary <- callsummary[,-1]    

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


callsummary$Contact <- as.character(callsummary$Contact)

df <- callsummary %>% 
    group_by(Direction, Bill) %>% 
    arrange(desc(Amount)) %>%  
    mutate(Index = 1:n(), Contact = ifelse(Index > 3, "Other", Contact))

df2 <- df %>% group_by(Direction) %>% summarise(Y = mean(Amount))


ggplot(df, aes(x = Bill, y = Amount)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Contact)) + 
    facet_grid( ~ Direction) + 
    labs(list(title = "Monthly Call Summary", x = "Month", y = "Total Call duration in Minutes")) + 
    geom_hline(data = df2, aes(yintercept = Y))
```

[image]

**Data** (after removing the first column)

```
structure(list(Direction = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("In", 
"Out"), class = "factor"), Contact = c("D28", "D10", "D18", "D3", 
"D10", "D18", "D3", "D18", "D10", "D18", "D21", "D27", "D13", 
"D3", "D10", "D3", "D21", "D22", "D23", "D17", "D13", "D15", 
"D18", "D21", "D2", "D8", "D1", "D15", "D23", "D23", "D18", "D11", 
"D16", "D21", "D24", "D3", "D25", "D15", "D10", "D9", "D22", 
"D19", "D10", "D3", "D8", "D12", "D13", "D15", "D17", "D19", 
"D19", "D20", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D11", "D13", "D14", "D15", 
"D17", "D19", "D20", "D21", "D22", "D22", "D26", "D27", "DNA"
), Bill = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("April", 
"June", "May"), class = "factor"), Amount = c(56.3, 20.6, 16.3, 
16, 15.9, 14.3, 11.2, 10.8, 9.1, 8, 7.4, 6.9, 6.4, 5.3, 5.1, 
5, 4.6, 3.9, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2.8, 2.4, 2.4, 2.4, 
2.3, 2.3, 2, 2, 2, 1.9, 1.5, 1.4, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.2, 1.1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), NA. = c(0, 0, 2.45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.77, 0.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.35, 0, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0.29, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.18, 0, 0.17, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Direction", 
"Contact", "Bill", "Amount", "NA."), row.names = c(NA, -69L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I need a way to index/rank such that for each category (In and Out) and each month I have different rankings, so that I can show the top 3 and others for each month and each category in the plot

Comment: @Sumedh- yes, top 3 for each month within each category (direction). Checked on my dataset and getting a plot similar to what u have posted and not top 3 for each month within each category/direction. Will load my entire dataset shortly.

Comment: @Sumedh- my dataset has been added.

Comment: @Sumedh- its just a 3KB file.. if u dont mind sharing ur email address, I can email it to u

Comment: @Sumedh- I have added a dropbox link to the csv file.  For some reason I am not able to format the output of dput correctly in the stackflow code mode. Also the output of dput has some irrelevant data which I have removed when cleaning the data but am not sure why some of it shows up in the output of dput (levels and column names of previous steps).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so create month-specific variables, like...

```
callsummary$June <- NA

callsummary$June[callsummary$Bill %in% sort(
    callsummary$Duration, 
    decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]] <- callsummary$Bill[
        callsummary$Bill %in% sort(
            callsummary$Duration, 
            decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]]

callsummary$June[!callsummary$Bill %in% callsummary$Bill[sort(
    callsummary$Duration, 
    decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]] <- "Others"
```

Comment: If I pass ord_df to ggplot, I will lose the data from rest of the rows. I am looking for a way to still show these rows in the stacked barplot but they should be under "Others".

Comment: So you're looking for a way to decide any non-top-3 bill as "others"? callsummary$Bill[!callsummary$Bill %in% callsummary$Bill[sort(callsummary$Duration, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]] <- "Others"

Comment: this approach (callsummary$Bill[!callsummary$Bill %in% callsummary$Bill[sort(callsummary$Duration, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]] <- "Others") will tag the non-top 3 entries of callsummary as "Others". I want to do this for each month without having to split it into different different dataframes for each month as I need all the data to be in the same dataframe to generate the box plot.

Comment: Ahh okay, so take that same approach but use it to create month-specific variables. Edited my original comment to reflect this.